# DC motor selection criteria: number of poles

Tags: dc-motor, design, torque

I’m designing a system to measure an arbitrary motor torque curve. As an active load, I’m searching for a brushed DC motor that is able to withstand some degree of torque and speed as well as comply with some other requirements in my system. I have already evaluated and narrowed down the possibilities based on the manufacture datasheet. However there are still some options with very close specifications but different number of poles in the rotor. My question is, what kind of system parameters should I use to determine the best number of poles in my application? Do they influence vibration? Smoothness when measuring torque? I really appreciate your insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your variations of poles and torque with max RPM.

You may want to choose a multiphase reluctance motor bigger than all devices under test or  the ability to parallel more than one active load each calibrated for input vs T vs RPM.  Generally the motors with lower DCR produce more torque and fewer poles more RPM/V.

To span a wide combination of devices under test , you would have to compare costs of having 1 huge motor that has more start and high RPM torque for braking or make it flexible with multiple smaller motor options.

Poles are like transmission gears so you can practically test a 200Rpm vs a 6000 RPM motor with the same active load but it becomes more costly as Hp increases unless you use belts and pulleys which must be lossless

In order to make a smooth motor tester you will want the ability to add a flywheel to reduce the dynamic pulsing of each motor  .   This means less averaging of the signal from the load cell and unexpected vibrations.

Comment: Hello, Tony. Thank you very much for this explanation. That really helped me to search for further details to my application!